# PyMongo query taking 40 seconds exactly everytime

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am using pymongo to query from a MongoDb collection based on time. Here is the query:

```
# start is just 1 day behind utc time in ISO format. eg "2022-01-31 07:36:39"
start=(datetime.now(timezone.utc)-timedelta(days=1)).replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None).isoformat(' ')

for value in db.collection.find({'time':{'$gte':start}}):
    print(value)
```

The query runs fine but it is taking exactly 40 seconds always. When I run the above query it just pauses half-way and then prints the rest of it.

And here are my execution stats:

> {'executionSuccess': True, 'nReturned': 18081, 'executionTimeMillis':
> 31, 'totalKeysExamined': 18081, 'totalDocsExamined': 18081,
> 'executionStages': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'nReturned': 18081,
> 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 2, 'works': 18082, 'advanced': 18081,
> 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 18, 'restoreState': 18,
> 'isEOF': 1, 'docsExamined': 18081, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage':
> {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 18081, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate':
> 0, 'works': 18082, 'advanced': 18081, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0,
> 'saveState': 18, 'restoreState': 18, 'isEOF': 1, 'keyPattern':
> {'time': 1}, 'indexName': 'time_1', 'isMultiKey': False,
> 'multiKeyPaths': {'time': []}, 'isUnique': False, 'isSparse': False,
> 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward',
> 'indexBounds': {'time': ['["2022-01-31 10:17:46", {})']},
> 'keysExamined': 18081, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped':
> 0}}, 'allPlansExecution': []}

One thing which I noticed was this was not happening before. Could it be any kind of network error?

Comment: Your execution stats says time in milliseconds and way less that reported.

Comment: @Gibbs yes so it should take around 31 ms to display all the returned values but it doesn't.

Comment: I think thats not true. After fetch, your results depends on the network too. Someone could comment on this also.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have some suspicions as to what might be happening here, somewhat along the lines of what @Gibbs was mentioning. Happy to add an answer in that regard if it might still be helpful

Comment: @user20042973 Never resolved but moved on from that project. I would still like to know why it was happening. Thanks!